# Object doesn't support his property or method when I set a button object in Edge

Tags: excel, vba, button

I set button object of Edge in excel VBA, but it always reports "Object doesn't support his property or method". This method is supported in IE but not in Edge. Could anyone help with it?
My VBA script is below.

```vb
Sub Query_Edge()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim edgePath As String
    Dim appEdge As Object
    Dim myButton As Object
    Dim i As Range
    Dim iRow As Long
    
    edgePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
    
    Set appEdge = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    
    appEdge.ShellExecute edgePath, "http://test.abc.com/Home", "", "", 1
    
    Do Until Not appEdge.Windows(0) Is Nothing
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    Set appEdge = appEdge.Windows(0)
    
    Do While appEdge.Busy Or Not appEdge.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
**Set myButton = appEdge.Document.getElementById("btn_mainsearch")**

Dim htmlDoc As HTMLDocument: Set htmlDoc = appEdge.Document
        
   For Each i In Selection
        iRow = i.Row

        htmlDoc.getElementById("box_mainsearch").Value = Cells(iRow, "A").Value
        
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        
        myButton.Click
        
        Do While appEdge.Document.readyState <> "complete"
            DoEvents
        Loop
        
        Do While htmlDoc.getElementById("table_result") Is Nothing
            DoEvents
        Loop
        
        If Not htmlDoc.getElementById("table_result").getElementsByTagName("td")(11) Is Nothing Then
            Cells(iRow, "O") = htmlDoc.getElementById("table_result").getElementsByTagName("td")(11).innerText
        End If
        
        If Not htmlDoc.getElementById("table_result").getElementsByTagName("td")(12) Is Nothing Then
            Cells(iRow, "R") = htmlDoc.getElementById("table_result").getElementsByTagName("td")(12).innerText
        End If
        
        If Not htmlDoc.getElementById("table_result").getElementsByTagName("td")(13) Is Nothing Then
            Cells(iRow, "Q") = htmlDoc.getElementById("table_result").getElementsByTagName("td")(13).innerText
        End If
        
        If Not htmlDoc.getElementById("table_result").getElementsByTagName("td")(9) Is Nothing Then
            Cells(iRow, "G") = htmlDoc.getElementById("table_result").getElementsByTagName("td")(9).innerText
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I tried "getElementByTagName" or "getElementsByClassName" to define the button, but no work.

Comment: Edge does not support the same as IE. Have a look at Selenium for Chrome